# What is missing in an insert query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Dim_Date ON

INSERT INTO Dim_Date ([Date_Key], [Date], [Full_Date], [Day_Of_Month], [Day_Name], [Day_Of_Week], [Day_Of_Week_In_Month], 
            [Day_Of_Week_In_Year], [Day_Of_Quarter], [Day_Of_Year], [Week_Of_Month], [Week_Of_Quarter], [Week_Of_Year], 
            [Month], [Month_Name], [Month_Of_Quarter], [Quarter], [Quarter_Name], [Year], [Year_Name], [Month_Year], 
            [MM_YYYY], [First_Day_Of_Month], [Last_Day_Of_Month], [First_Day_Of_Quarter], [Last_Day_Of_Quarter], 
            [First_Day_Of_Year], [Last_Day_Of_Year], [Is_Holiday], [Is_Weekday], [Holiday]) 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Dim_Date OFF

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '01/01/2010' -- Starting value of date range
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '08/12/2016' -- End Value of date range
```

The error message states

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'

What is missing between [Holiday]) and `SET`?

Thanks.

Comment: something to insert?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You only have half of an `INSERT` statement.  For brevity, you have this:

```
INSERT Into Dim_Date ([Date_Key], ..., [Holiday])
```

Which means you forgot the values that you're inserting.  Something more like this:

```
INSERT Into Dim_Date ([Date_Key], ..., [Holiday]) VALUES ('some value', ..., 'another value')
```

Finish the `INSERT` statement to include what you're inserting.  Otherwise, what would you expect to be inserted?